# Web to Case, unable to create an PersonAccount using form data

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, web2case

I have written a trigger which runs from the Web to Case HTML form. When I populate form (First, LastName, Phone, email etc), I want the Account to be created first and then link that account to the created case. Note that I have Account as a PersonAccount.

So when I am populating the data and inserting record nothing is added into the Account. Whats the issue? I dont see any errors also.

I have taken a reference from the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Autocreating_Contacts_From_Web_To_Case and changed Contact to Account in this code.

It looks to me that there are many triggers Active on the Account object, IO think some of the trigger is deleting my Account. No sure though but I see AccountId is in logs.

```
Account accnt = new Account();
accnt.FirstName = suppliedFirstName;
accnt.LastName = suppliedLastNamel;
accnt.PersonEmail=caseObj.SuppliedEmail;                         
accnt.Phone = caseObj.SuppliedPhone;
accnt.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId(); 
System.debug('Account Details To be Created :: '+ accnt);

phoneToAccountMap.put(caseObj.SuppliedPhone, accnt);
System.debug('phoneToAccountMap :: '+phoneToAccountMap);

casesToUpdate.add(caseObj);

List<Account> newAccounts = phoneToAccountMap.values();
insert newAccounts;
```

Comment: Could you please post the code. So that we can see whats wrong.

Comment: Any updates from Salesforce expert?